# Is there a version Canon SDK that runs under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, canon-sdk

I have an application that uses the Canon SDK. After I upgraded to Windows 10, I get the error

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
```

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: 0xc000007b = STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, this happens when you mix CPU architectures (x86/x64) of DLLs/Exe files. Reinstall the SDK

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (v3.05 at time of writing) does work with Windows 10, 64 bit.

This also solves the problem I had with this error

```
EdsImage.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error.
Error status 0xc000012f.
```